# map ConcurrentModificationException in for header

Tags: java, exception, dictionary, guava, concurrentmodification

I have the following code:

```
private Multimap<Object, ComplexCalcStrategy> strategies = HashMultimap.create();
....
Collection<ComplexCalcStrategy> strategiesThatNeedUpdating = strategies.get(mktDataChange.getOptionId());
for (ComplexCalcStrategy strategy : strategiesThatNeedUpdating) {  //row number 88
     updateMarketData(strategy.getStrategy(), mktDataChange);
}
```

and in logs I see following trace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedCollection$WrappedIterator.next(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:486)
    at package.ClassName.processMarketDataChange(ClassName.java:88)
```

I don't understand how does this code can produce CME.

Please, share your ideas.

P.S.

map fills here:

```
@Override
public void registerStrategy(final ComplexCalcStrategy strategy) {
    for (Integer optionId : strategy.getOptions()) {
        strategies.put(optionId, strategy);

    }
    if (strategy.getStrategy().tiedToStock) {
        strategies.put(strategy.getUnderlying(), strategy);
    }

    ....
}
```

This method invokes in another thread and looks like sometime iteration and map filling happens simultaneously and it is root cause.

I understand that I can use synchronized version of multimap.

Will it fix issue?

Is there nicer way?

Comment: Are you attempting to alter the collection you are iterating over within your for loop? eg calling remove/add etc

Comment: What happens in your for loop?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman added code to topic

Comment: And what happens in `updateMarketData`?

Comment: I'm guessing that strategiesThatNeedUpdating is the keySet of a Map?

Comment: @beresfordt it doesn't write in stacktrace thus doesn't matter

Comment: It does matter. If you modify a collection while iterating over it you'll get the error in the for statement.

Comment: @gstackoverflow, it _definitely_ matters.  This is how ConcurrentModificationExceptions work.

Comment: @Paul Boddington **view collection of the values associated with {@code key} in this
   * multimap **

Comment: @Paul Boddington inside this method I see only getter invocation

Comment: @Louis Wasserman according stacktrace I don't see updateMarketData method invocation

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, that's right.  That doesn't matter, you wouldn't expect it to show up in the stack trace, but that doesn't mean `updateMarketData` isn't causing the error -- if you're getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`, it's extremely likely that something in `updateMarketData` is causing it _even though_ `updateMarketData` doesn't appear in the stack trace.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman topic updated

Comment: Hmmmkay.  Where does `strategies` get filled?  How does data get put into it?

Comment: This is too complicated to answer as your methods all call other methods. You need to use a debugger to step through this. Somewhere in that method call you're modifying the Map whose keys you're iterating over.

Comment: @Paul Boddington I cannot reproduce it. I have found it in logs

Comment: The repeated updates which still cut out code don't help either. For people to help you really need to show all the code which is involved.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman topic updated

Comment: @Paul Boddington topic updated

Comment: @beresfordt topic updated

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

[ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

If you modify the keys/values in a `Multimap` during iteration of the keys/values then you cannot continue iterating after the modification (hence the exception).

Consider using [`Multimaps.transformValues(Multimap, Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#transformValues(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) instead.

Comment: I don't transform values - I put new

Comment: @gstackoverflow A `put` is a modification to the keys/values (a.k.a. entires) of the multimap.