# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException while iterating over map.entrySet

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have the following code:

```
static final Map<String, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        map.put("1", "1");
        map.put("2", "2");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("after iterator");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(50);
        map.remove("1");
        System.out.println("removed");
    }
```

It produces `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

How can I avoid it ?

Comment: Make the run method synchronized.. or your can use concurrent hashmap  .  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug ConcurrentModificationException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840165/how-to-debug-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: Looks like essentially the same as you previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228084/map-concurrentmodificationexception-in-for-header

Comment: use `ConcurrentHashMap`. Iterators in `.synchronizedMap()` are not synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove an element from a collection while iterating it, unless you use an Iterator. Use Iterator.remove() method

Comment: fail save iterator ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `static final Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

```
    static final Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    map.put("1", "1");
    map.put("2", "2");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("after iterator");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }).start();

    Thread.sleep(50);
    map.remove("1");
    System.out.println("removed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a `Collections.synchronizedMap` you must explicitly synchronize the iteration:

```
        synchronized (map) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("after iterator");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
         }
```

Comment: looks like I can use simple HasMap at this case

Comment: No.  You must synchronize both the iteration and all other operations on the map, and synchronizedMap is the way to do that.